how to filter by field in fuzzy elastic search query
I can fuzzy search in elastic by company name in the following way:
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/companies_test/_search -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
       "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "match": {
                "name": {
                  "query": "openAI",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }'

it returns
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "companies_test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "0",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "regionName": "North America",
          "name": "OpenAI",
          "id": "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

But when I try to add regionName filter to it:
 curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/companies_test/_search -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
       "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "match": {
                "name": {
                  "query": "openai",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "regionName": "North America"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }'

it returns 0 results:
{
  "took": 38,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}

How to fix my elastic search query to fuzzy search by company name in specific regionName?
Update
here is my document structure:
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/companies_test/_mapping -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

returns:
{
  "companies_test": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "regionName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Also I tried to search and filter by lowered case text but it gives no result as well.
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/companies_test/_search -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
       "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "match": {
                "name": {
                  "query": "open ai",
                  "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "regionName": "north america"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }'

returns
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}


Дорогой Максим, я не зря посоветовал Вам углубить свои знания в Вашем предыдущем вопросе. Вы вновь наступаете на теже грабли. Если вместо "OpenAI" нужно искать "openai", то почему Вы ищите "North America" вместо "north america"? Пожалуйста, разберитесь в отличиях full text search от term search. Точный правильный ответ на этот (и предыдущий) вопрос Вам никто не даст, пока Вы не поделитесь структурой документа. Какого типа поля name и regionName: text или keyword? Какой индексатор или нормализатор Вы используете?

@G0l0s thank you for your effort, added answers to your questions in the update above

Thanks for a mapping
There are two ways to transform your filter
I.  Using the term query, a keyword multifield and an original text
      "term": {
        "regionName.keyword": "North America"
      }

II. Using the match query, a text multifield and a lowercased text
      "match": {
        "regionName": "north america"
      }

